# How to insert same value to different fields of different objects in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, create-records

How to insert same value to different fields of different objects. I am working in Visual workflow where I am getting a set of information on a screen. Now I need to insert these records into 3 different objects. Is it possible by using Record Create palette, do I need to have 3 separate Record Create palette how can I connect 3 Record Create palette to a single screen. Or is their any other way to solve this issue. Eg : I am getting First Name, Last Name, Company name from a screen now I need to insert it into 3 standard object as 3 separate records. 3 objects are - Account, Contact and opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to reference the Screen Input value for that input in all of your creates.  You are able to connect your Record Creates together, so that you do one after another.

Normally I would tell you to do a Fast Create to add in multiple records at once, however you're not dealing with the same Object type for all the records so that changes things :).  Now based on your comment, you need to make it all in this way:

Screen --> Record Create of Account, set the Account ID --> Create Contact with Account ID --> Create Opportunity with Account ID

See my below screen shot for how to do this (note I set the ID to a variable to re-use later in the Flow):
[image]

Comment: what if I need to save the same company name to contact and opportunity after the account is created.

Comment: You can re-use the same input multiple times.